# API call using Retrofit2: How can I make API calls all the time, to update the data without reopening the app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

In a Livescores app, how can I make the results of matches updated without reopening the app?
Here is my code sample for ViewModel, if anyone can help.

```
@HiltViewModel
class LiveMatchesViewModel @Inject constructor(private val liveMatchesRepository: LiveMatchesRepository): ViewModel() {

    private var _liveMatchesState = MutableStateFlow<MatchState>(MatchState.Empty)
    val liveMatchesState: StateFlow<MatchState> =  _liveMatchesState

    init {
        getAllLiveMatches()
    }

    private fun getAllLiveMatches() {
        _liveMatchesState.value = MatchState.Loading

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

            try {
                val liveMatchesResponse = liveMatchesRepository.getLiveMatches()
                _liveMatchesState.value = MatchState.Success(liveMatchesResponse)
            }
            catch (exception: HttpException) {
                _liveMatchesState.value = MatchState.Error("Something went wrong")
            }
            catch (exception: IOException) {
                _liveMatchesState.value = MatchState.Error("No internet connection")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tenfour04 No, I mean while using the app. What I mean is that every time a goal is scored or a match starts, the API changes, but this does not affect the app without closing it and opening it again to recall the API data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using a [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect) Composable:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    while (true) {
        liveMatchesViewModel.getAllLiveMatches()
        delay(20000)  // wait for 20 seconds
    }
}
```

This will re-execute the `getAllLiveMatches` function every 20 seconds. You need to make `getAllLiveMatches` a public function to make this work.

With this approach, the refreshing will be cancelled when the Composable leaves the composition. You need to judge yourself if this is what you want.

As an alternative, you can execute the same code in the ViewModel in a `viewModelScope`. The [`launch`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) function returns a [`Job`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/) that you can cancel when the ViewModel is destroyed using the [`onCleared`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel#oncleared) callback.

```
// ...
private var refreshingJob: Job? = null

init {
    getAllLiveMatches()
}

private fun getAllLiveMatches() {

    if (refreshingJob != null) return
    refreshingJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

        while(true) {

            _liveMatchesState.value = MatchState.Loading
            try {
                val liveMatchesResponse = liveMatchesRepository.getLiveMatches()
                _liveMatchesState.value = MatchState.Success(liveMatchesResponse)
            } catch (exception: HttpException) {
                _liveMatchesState.value = MatchState.Error("Something went wrong")
            } catch (exception: IOException) {
                _liveMatchesState.value = MatchState.Error("No internet connection")
            }

            delay(20000)  // wait for 20 seconds
        }
    }
}

// This will be called when the ViewModel is going to be destroyed
override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    refreshingJob?.cancel()
}
```

This will refresh the data as long as the ViewModel lives, which might be different from the time that the Composable displaying the data is visible.

Answer (score 1):

Making API calls "all the time" sounds like you'r `DDoS`ing yourself....

In case you are in control of the server, i suggest using websockets instead.
They're a top-pick for applications like messaging apps or small games.

In case you're not in control of the server:

- expect the server limiting how often you can do calls
- research the cost per call

Comment: For now, I'm not in control of the server.
I'm on the free plan with 100/day API calls; until the time of release, I will not add this to my project. I just wanted to know the best ways to do that approach.